# Presence of a particular character in a string

Tags: python, string, character

How to check if a string has at least one of certain character?

If the string `cool = "Sam!"`, how do i check to see if that string has at least one `!`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `in` operator

```
>>> cool = "Sam!"
>>> '!' in cool
True
>>> '?' in cool
False
```

As you can see `'!' in cool` returns a boolean and can be used further in your code

Answer (score 2):

In Python, a string is a sequence (like an array); therefore, the `in` operator can be used to check for the existence of a character in a Python string. The `in` operator is used to assert membership in a sequence such as strings, lists, and tuples.

```
cool = "Sam!"
'!' in cool # True
```

Alternately you can use any of the following for more information:

```
cool.find("!") # Returns index of "!" which is 3
cool.index("!") # Same as find() but throws exception if not found
cool.count("!") # Returns number of instances of "!" in cool which is 1
```

More info that you may find helpful:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_strings.htm

Answer (score 1):

Use the following

```
cool="Sam!"
if "!" in cool:
    pass # your code
```

Or just:

```
It_Is="!" in cool
# some code
if It_Is:
    DoSmth()
else:
    DoNotDoSmth()
```